# Call values from a file and run the code with Python

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import itertools
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.interpolate
import numpy as np, pylab
import os
from numpy import split


with open('zzz.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        line = (line.split('=')[1].strip().split(','))
        line = list(map(float, line))
        print (line)


tck = interpolate.bisplrep(xx, yy, zz, s=0)

def givemeTL(X2,Y2):
    return interpolate.bisplev(X2,Y2,tck)
```

file (zzz.txt) include:

```
xx = 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55 
yy = 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09
zz = 0.75, 0.81, 0.83, 1.00, 0.92, 0.91, 0.745, 0.805, 0.82
```

I keep getting error 
ValueError: could not convert string to float: `'xx = 0.15'`

I am facing this problem everytime, where calling the values is part of running the code. But everytime I am changing the calling method it gives me error.
How can I fix it?
Best Regards

Comment: The file operation works fine for me: prints three lists of float numbers. I saw you edited your question. Did you really update your actual question?

Comment: please don't change code in question - now our answers has no sense with your question. You should add new code at the end of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will not create variable `xx` but I will create dictionary with  `data['xx']` - it is prefered method.

```
data = {} # dict for data from file

with open('zzz.txt') as fp:

    for line in fp:
        variable, numbers = line.split('=')

        variable = variable.strip()

        numbers = numbers.split(',')
        numbers = list(map(float, numbers))

        data[variable] = numbers
```

after that you can get `xx` as `data['xx']`

```
print(data['xx'])
```

or you can assign to variable

```
xx = data['xx']
```

---

Instead of `data[variable] = numbers` you can use `globals()[variable] = numbers` and you get variable `xx` without doing `xx = data['xx']` but people say it is not prefered method.

Comment: I was facing this problem everytime, where calling the values is part of running the code. I dont want to keep the values inside the code. But everytime I call them from a file it gives xx is not defined

Comment: It seams your code expect variable `xx` but you didn't create it. You have to read data from file and assign to variable `xx` - ie. `xx = data['xx']` .

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Comment: BTW: instead of `data[variable] = numbers` you can do `globals()[variable] = numbers` and you get variable `xx` without doing `xx = data['xx']` but people say it is not prefered method.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {}
with open('zzz.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        var, values = list(map(str.strip, line.split('=')))
        values = list(map(float, values.split(',')))
        data[var] = values
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I got this error, NameError: name 'xx' is not defined.

Comment: @user8670370 this method doesn't create variable `xx` it only read every  line and convert to list which you can assign to different variables. You could use list or dictionary to keep more than last line.

Comment: sure i didn't read the question properly surely it can be dict with key as `xx` and value as a list of values

Comment: @armak you can still change code to make better example :)